# Multi-level Registration in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

How to implement two type of registration like student and teacher?
I need two type of registration one for Teacher and one for Student. Both are different registration and both have different roles. Is it possible in Drupal? And also I need registering Student there is no admin approval but for Teacher registration, admin approval is required. How can I achieve this in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 2):

In the custom user registration form add one more select box field with ROLE TYPE (student, teacher).Then on the submit hook check like shown below.

> ```
> function add_student_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
>
> $fields = array();
> $fields['is_new'] = true;
> $fields['name'] = $form_state['values']['user_name'];
> $fields['pass'] = $form_state['values']['pass'];
>
> $role_type = $form_state['values']['role_type'];
>
> //Add the user to the corresponding role
> $fields['roles'] = array($role_type)
>
> //here you can achieve the thing which you want.If the role is a teacher then set 
> //status = 0, else status = 1
> if($role_type == 'student')
>   $fields['status'] = 1;
> else
>   $fields['status'] = 0;    // $user = user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $fields);  //This works in D7 
>
> $user = user_save('', $fields);  //pretty sure this is what works in D6 }
> ```

If the user is the teacher you should go to http://localhost/domain_name/admin/user/user. Here you can filter the Inactive users and activate them.

Answer (score 2):

hey you can use below modules for creating multilevel registration.

http://drupal.org/project/content_profile
http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole

above modules help you to create multilevel registration form in site. from content profile you can create form and also give auto assign role to student.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i'm aware, drupal doesn't provide any mechanism for having multiple types of registration forms.  However you can fairly easily create your own registration form from scratch.  All you really need is the user_save function to create a new user.  See the sample code below as part of a form_submit hook

```
function add_student_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    $fields = array();
    $fields['is_new'] = true;
    $fields['name'] = $form_state['values']['user_name'];
    $fields['pass'] = $form_state['values']['pass'];
    $fields['status'] = 1;

   // $user = user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $fields);  //This works in D7 
    $user = user_save('', $fields);  //pretty sure this is what works in D6
}
```

Using this you can create whatever custom logic you want for each form